# OrientDB 2.2.2 - How to manually detect if cluster was softly closed? Rely on index auto rebuild?

Tags: orientdb

We are upgrading from 1.4.1 to 2.2.2. Previously, we were rebuilding indexes of the database manually if we detected that a OMetadataDefault.CLUSTER_INDEX_NAME is not softly closed by calling

```
!(OStorageLocal)db.getStorage().isClusterSoftlyClosed(OMetadataDefault.CLUSTER_INDEX_NAME);
```

This was because in previous versions, the index rebuilding use to rebuild all indexes, which in turn resulted in long startup times.

From what I can tell, isClusterSoftlyClosed is no longer present in 2.2.2, but haven't been able to find an alternative. Is there an alternative here, or are we suppose to rely on the asynchronous index auto rebuilding? Is OrientDB smart enough to decide which indexes are bad and only rebuild the ones that are needed, or rebuild indexes faster now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrientDB v2.2 takes care to rebuild the index that need to, so forget about it.

Comment: Thanks @Lvca! Appreciate it!